# Splitting "latitude, longitude" string for circle geolocation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

pretty new to d3 & js here. I'm trying to geolocate d3 circles from a csv file which has a combined lat/long string column (e.g. "44.999572, -93.351774". I'm able to do achieve this when I have separate lat & long columns in the csv, but I haven't been able to split a combined string. I've attached the code in question that works (with 2 columns) -- how would split a single latlon column?

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

d3.queue()
  .defer(d3.json, "map.geojson")     
  .defer(d3.csv, "circles.csv")   
  .await(ready);

svg
  .selectAll("myCircles")
  .data(data.sort(function(a,b) { return +b.n - +a.n }).filter(function(d,i){ return i<10 }))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d){ return projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[0] })
    .attr("cy", function(d){ return projection([+d.lon, +d.lat])[1] })
    .attr("r", 5)
    .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.n) })
    .attr("stroke", "black")
    .attr("stroke-width", 0)
    .attr("fill-opacity", .6);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If your `circles.csv` has just one column for latitudes and longitudes, say `latlon`, you can use a row conversion function for creating the two properties, `lat` and `lon`, and use your current code as it is. Also, since you're using `d3.queue`, I assume you're using D3 version 4.

Here's an example using `d3.csvParse`, but the logic is the same, just add the row function in your `defer` arguments:

```js
const csv = `name,latlon
foo,"44,35"
bar,"-12,39"
baz,"17,-5"`;

const data = d3.csvParse(csv, row);

console.log(data)

function row(d) {
  const latLonArray = d.latlon.split(",").map(e => +e);
  d.lat = latLonArray[0];
  d.lon = latLonArray[1];
  return d;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/7.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Gerardo. Can you clarify how I would add the row function to my defer arguments?

Comment: @organon that would be `.defer(d3.csv, "circles.csv", row)`.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately I'm having trouble including the rest of your d3.csvParse example into my code. I'm not declaring a `const csv =`, as I'm using `.defer`, therefore I can't declare the `const data = d3.csvParse(csv, row);`... Can you show me how it would look in my example? Many thanks